# Comparison word cloud query not making sense

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

I have used the "comparison.cloud" function in wordcloud package in R. For example below is my data matrix. I have two questions:

1. The word 'employee' appeared in both joy (22 times) and unknown(10 times) categories however on the wordcloud it appears only under 'unknown' catergory for some reasons. Does 'employee' should appear under categories 'anger', 'joy', 'sadness','unknown'? or it should reflect under one category that is 'joy'(as it has max. frequency)? Why it is not appearing under 'joy'category in comparison word cloud?
2. Under 'joy' category in comparison word cloud, the words appearing is 'people', 'respect', 'try', 'work' but not 'employee', 'management'. 'management' is getting highlighted in big font under surprise category.

Present comparison word cloud is not making any sense if i am comparing with matrix data. Is there any wrong in my code? Please guide me.

Below is the code:

```
 set.seed(142)
 comparison.cloud(tdm, colors = brewer.pal(nemo, "Dark2"),max.words=200,
             scale = c(1,.5), random.order = FALSE, title.size = 1.5,rot.per=0.2)
```

Data looks like this matrix:

```
               anger     joy     sadness    surprise     unknown
 company         1        12       0           0            5
 employee        1        22       1           0            10
 good            0        17       0           0            0
 management      0        12       1           2            6
 people          0        9        0           0            2
 respect         0        6        0           0            0
 try             0        7        0           0            1
 work            0        7        1           0            3
```

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like `comparison.cloud()` is concerned not only with the frequency of a word's appearance in a particular document, but also with the relative frequency of that word's appearance across documents. If I'm getting that right, then it would explain why "people", "management", etc. show up under `joy` while the more common words do not, and why employee shows up under `unknown`.

Comment: Thanks....Can you please share me the link of the documentation?

Comment: It's [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf). See esp. Details under comparison.cloud on p. 3. For future reference, Googling "[package or function name] r" will quickly get you to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is helpful.